# Remove the play icon displayed on audio and video files in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, ui

Is there a way to remove the play icon displayed on video and audio files when using icon view mode?

They are extremely annoying. When accidentally clicking on them, audio starts playing in the background and you don't know where it comes from or how to stop it.
Also when trying to double click a file you must click besides the play icon on a very small area.

I really don't know why this is considered a feature worth keeping. But maybe that's just me.

**EDIT:**

While the suggestion below to turn off the icon preview works, this turns off every preview for every file, which is not what I want. Are there any (third party) alternatives?

This is the icon I meant:

[image]

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this overlay? I can only get it in column view when I hover the preview.

Comment: It shows in icon view as well @Tetsujin.

Comment: I'm using Icon view. The image is one file inside a folder.

Comment: ah, OK. This seems to be a new addition. Doesn't do it on older OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is part of the Finder icon preview function which you can disable  with the Command - J shortcut whenever the play icon overlay control is visible.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-preview-pane-in-the-finder-on-mac-mchl1e4644c2/mac

[image: Finder view options window with Show icon Preview disabled]

Once you have things as you like, select the "Use as Defaults" control at the bottom of the View options window.

Comment: Thanks. While this works it also completely removes any previews of any other file (which are not media files). That's not something I would like to have. I could disable it for each folder separately, but that's quiet a lot of work.

Comment: You may have to choose unless someone knows a different solution.  I get the down side, but this has been baked into the system for quite a long time @Marc What's the cause of the errant clicks?

Comment: Sorry could you clarify your question?

Comment: Why do you click accidentally on something you know will start playback?

Comment: If I want to open the file via double click, I need to click besides the play icon which is only a very thin area. So accidental clicks on the play icon happen quiet often. Or if I hover over a file and accidentally tap my touchpad, I click on the play icon and have no indication from where the sound is coming.

Comment: There are views other than icon which will not display this - & also will show you far more info in far less space than icon view.

Comment: I am so used to icon view, I cannot change. The other views don't give me any info I need, since 95% of the time I work purely in terminal.